# How the render process is going in React?

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

I just starting to get confused about the render process in React.

Let's say I've got a Higher Order Component what looks something like this:

```
const withHOC = () => WrapperComponent =>  {
    return class WithHOC extends React.Component {
        render() {
            //someProps => what will change...
            //...rest => won't change
            const { someProps, ...rest } = this.props
            return(
                <WrapperComponent {...rest} />
            )
        }
    }
}
```

This is where I am quite confused...
as `someProps` will change the HOC itself will re-render. Is this means the WrappedComponent will be re-rendered as well?

I mean the WrappedComponent's props not changing.
And how expensive can this be?

Comment: It looks like you're missing a `return`, just FYI.

Comment: Ahh, yeah... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React HOC is not a big deal to understand when you think it as just a parent component.

**Now, guess what happens when child component receive the props from the parent component?**

The child component will be re-rendered.

**What happens to the parent component render?**

The parent component is also re-rendered because its props changes.

---

The same thing applies to the HOC. Thus, WrapperComponent will also re-render whenever the props / state changes.

Comment: Even if I won't pass down the prop what changed to the child, it's still re-render?

Comment: @IstvanOrban Yes,, but you can cancel it with `shouldComponentUpdate` callback inside the `WrapperComponent`..Like if `rest` props are same, dismiss the render.. that way you save your extra rendering..

Comment: I see, that where I was really confused. I mean the children's props didn't changed, yet it's updating... The same apply to PureComponent's as well?

Comment: @IstvanOrban you may take this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51894190/why-setstate-from-parent-component-calling-child-componentdidupdate/51894796#51894796

Comment: @IstvanOrban The linked post has the answer what you need to know.

Comment: @IstvanOrban `PureComponent` will work till __shallow prop and state comparison__ is happening.. If you are sure, `rest` props are just a flat object, not a single prop has nested data.. `PureComponent` is good choice.

Comment: I see, It's makes sense now.
I mean it's logical that when I node updating, then the subtree will get updated too. BUT then I can prevent this by either shouldComponentUpdate or a PureComponent. Thanks for making it clear guys! :)

Comment: @IstvanOrban If you use `PureComponent`, `shouldComponentUpdate` comes in built.. If you think props are not flat.. then use regular component, and implement your own `shouldComponentUpdate`..

Comment: So where I can let the built in shallow compare to do it's work (and do not need a custom logic), then it's should be fine?

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar means props are just `{x: '..', y: ''}`, not `{x: {a:1}, y: ""}`.. :)

Comment: @IstvanOrban Notice the console.log when you type only in the first input.. and when second or third.. https://codesandbox.io/s/n730pmrlo0

Comment: @ArupRakshit Ah, got it. Thanks. But was trying to find reference about flat props without success.